# Is it at all possible to determine whether the running browser is the default browser in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser

It would be very useful, in my application, to know whether the current browser is the default browser.

Is is possible, using JavaScript, to know whether the browser my page is opened in is the default browser (i.e. the browser that would open if I were to click on a link in another app. like, for example, an email reader)?

---

**Update**

To answer E. Sundin and other possible readers, there is the main reason why I would like to know whether the current browser is the default browser:

When a user registers on one of my websites, I register the `User-Agent` as a token that should not change between the time the user registers and the time the user clicks on the email verification link. Unfortunately, when users click on the link, it opens in the default browser.

If I knew, I could do several things:

1. Not put a link in the email, just ask the user to copy/paste the token to his still open browser
2. Warn the user as he is registering that it won't work if he just follows the link (if I know that this browser is not the default.)
3. Eventually ignore that test (that could be an admin. setup, in most cases website owners do not care that much... so not having such a test would be similar to nearly all other websites. Reduced security, but since the majority does that anyway...)

Of course, it happens that people register on their smart phone, receive their email on their desktop and follow the link there. That would also not work well with such a test...

Comment: Not as far as I know but then again your app should be browser and device agnostic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the use case of this desired feature?

Comment: I think that that shouldn't be necessary for anything, and because of that, it might not be in the standard, and then browsers might not act the same. Also, it's not guaranteed there's a possible way to do this, as the browser should keep at least some information private.

Comment: @E.Sundin I updated my question because that's a bit too long as a comment. There can be other reasons, but I give one of the main examples of why I think it is useful.

Comment: @MasterBob I'm not too sure that knowing whether the user is in his favorite browser is such a private information that it should not be divulged. But there are a few cases where it would help security if you're to force the user to use the same browser between a "forgot password" and "there is your token" type of process. One way is to not provide a URI in the email... but most people are used to just click on a URI...

Comment: @Jeff, many CMS, now a day, will send a session ID in a form. This is used to make sure that the following POST comes from the right client and that the client indeed got the form from the server (i.e. is not rePOSTing data using the same form, over and over again.) In other words, with my system I do not want a form to be loaded in Browser A and then the reply sent from Browser B. This eliminates many basic web spammers. Also knowing whether we are in the default browser does not mean my code would not work in any browser, does it?!

Comment: @AlexisWilke You can possibly check if the browsers are the same. I really doubt that a client would use one browser for your application while setting another browser as the default. Also, email shouldn't open it on the default browser.

Comment: @MasterBob Actually I had a case where a user registered on his cell phone and then followed the link on his desktop... but I have a user who uses three different browsers all the time and he will get that error quite often. I don't think that would be the majority of users, though, I totally agree on that.

Comment: @AlexisWilke you are talking about nonces. This wordpress article describes what they are and how to implement them (https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) admittedly in Wordpress but easy to create for your own system.

Comment: @jeff, _"Nonces should never be relied on for authentication or authorization, access control."_ — if this is true, then Wordpress cannot use a nonce to verify your email address. Note that I already have session IDs implemented, they have been for several years and work just fine. email verification still has a certain amount of flaws because the user browser used to verify the email address is not checked (at least in Wordpress or Drupal I've never seen code that would do such a thing, the only verification they do is the nonce.) By checking the browser your verification is way more secure.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no Javascript API for this.

Keep in mind that not all operating systems even have the concept of a "default browser".

Comment: Are you saying that some systems, such as smart phones, do not really have a default browser concept? I was not aware, although it probably makes sense.

Comment: Not all Linux desktops have a system-wide default browser. There's multiple ways that a default can _effectively_ be set, and they can potentially be in conflict with each other. (So a browser may not even be able to conclusively determine whether it's the default or not.) And some embedded systems -- including certain smartphones -- don't really have a settable default browser either.